# Tensorflow import issues on the anaconda virtual environment

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm using OS X now and got a problem with importing tensorflow.
I'm using anaconda and made a new virtual environment with python 3.7 and tensor flow 1.15.0.
I've no problem so far but from yesterday I got error massages like below

> import tensorflow as tf
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>    File
> "/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/python3.7_tf1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/**init**.py",
> line 99, in 
> from tensorflow_core import *   File "/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/python3.7_tf1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/**init**.py",
> line 28, in 
> from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import ImportError: cannot import name
> 'pywrap_tensorflow' from 'tensorflow_core.python' (unknown location)

I tried to make a new virtual environment and set the same setting but it didn't work neither.
what should I do?

Comment: You can try the solution given here
https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/4400#issuecomment-550905592

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.
The main issue was a directory of python file that I tried to run by using conda.
I moved that file out of problematic folder and it worked.